# Delphi: What is the quickest way to populate a dropdown box via a qry result?

Tags: delphi, drop-down-menu

Ok, so I have a database query, that returns the countryname column

```
 SELECT CountryName FROM Counties
```

How would I put all these country names into the dropdown boxes Items option (without looping through them?)

Comment: Well, people commonly use a data aware control for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use something like the TDBLookupComboBox.  Drop one on the form and set the properties like this.

```
  DataSource = srcCustomers
  DataField = 'country_id'

  ListSource = srcCountries
  ListField = 'NAME'
  KeyField = 'ID'
```

This code will display the country name on the form and place the country id in the db Customers.country_id.

The two controls that start with src are TDataSources connected to TADODataSets.  You can connect the datasources to many different data access controls.

Comment: Ok I was literally about to do some very bad coding! THanks for pointing out this lookup DB combo box. I never realised it existed :D Saved me alot of time and effort.

Comment: You're welcome.  I've had similar feature-shock experiences with Delphi, and I've used it since 1.0.  I once spent hours writing a function to return random numbers distributed over a bell-shaped curve instead of evenly.  Was testing it and noticed a few oddities in the data.  Started digging and found the randg() function that did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

My Delphi is a little rusty but you should have something along the line of ->

```
comboBox.Items //A list so you can just add to it.
```

you can then take your result, loop over it and deal with the issue like any other Windows framework. Look up the TADOQuery (or whatever you're using) to get the results. Delphi is pretty straightforward, inspect the object and you'll probably see a solution materialize.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like that:

```
ComboBox.Items.Assign(CountryList);
```

Where `CountryList` is a `TStringList` instance containing all country names.

This is the fastest way of populating a TComboBox.